# Pass a PHP variable to a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, variables

What is wrong with this code? I get an empty array. I am passing a PHP variable to the query, but it doesn’t work; when I give a hardcoded value the query returns a result.

```
echo $sub1 = $examSubject[$i];
$subType = $examType[$i];
$query = $this->db->query("select dSubject_id from tbl_subject_details where dSubjectCode='$sub1'");
print_r($query->result_array());
```

Comment: Knowing what's in `$sub1` might help -- or doing an echo of the whole query could too ;-)

Comment: @pascal $sub1 is a string representing subjectname

Comment: The question from Martin is: what do you get for echo $sub1; and echo $query;

Comment: @Saranya As Pascal wrote - dump the query string - if there is still null - dump `$examSubject` - you must had mistake with array keys then.

Comment: CS1 and 6 are the echos of $sub1 and $query

Comment: so the matching dSubject_id for CS1 is 6?

Comment: With `echo "select dSubject_id from tbl_subject_details where dSubjectCode='$sub1'";` you have still `dSubjectCode='CS1'"` ?

Comment: @Saranya it is sometimes helpful to test SQL code in phpMyAdmin before putting it into the php code

Comment: @hsz i got the result for dSubjectCode='CS1'

Comment: @konman i got result for SQL code in phpMyAdmin. I think php variable is the prob.

Comment: put the result of    
    echo "select dSubject_id from tbl_subject_details where dSubjectCode='$sub1'";
 in phpmyadmin->select_your_database->SQL(if your db is mysql)
 and check does it works or not?

Comment: in case of mysql you can do it:
mysql_query($query) or die('ERROR: ' . mysql_error());

does your API, have such a function to check last error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look up “SQL injection”.

I’m not familiar with `$this->db->query`; what database driver are you using? The syntax for escaping variables varies from driver to driver.

Here is a PDO example:

```
$preqry = "INSERT INTO mytable (id,name) VALUES (23,?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($preqry);

$stmt->bindparam(1,$name);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: +1, direct quoting of a variable into a query string is a bad habit which can land you in trouble :)

Answer (score 1):

failing to see what you database abstraction layer ($this->db) does, here's the adjusted code from example1 from [the mysql_fetch_assoc documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

```
<?php
  // replace as you see fit
  $sub1 = 'CS1';

  // replace localhost, mysql_user & mysql_password with the proper details
  $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
  if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
  }

  if (!mysql_select_db("mydbname")) {
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
  }

  $sql = 'SELECT `dSubject_id` ';
  $sql .= 'FROM `tbl_subject_details` ';
  $sql .= "WHERE `dSubjectCode` ='$sub1';";

  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
  }

  if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
  }

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['dSubject_id'];
  }

  mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

Let me know what the output is, I'm guessing it will say: 6

Answer (score 1):

Is it CodeIgniter framework you're using (from the $this->db->query statement). If so, why don't you try:

```
$this->db->where('dSubjectCode',$sub1);
$query = $this->db->get('tbl_subject_details');
```

If this doesn't work, you've got an error earlier in the code and $sub1 isn't what you expect it to be.