# how to pass the php variable in Mysql select Query

Tags: php

`$valid` is An array and `$createdon` and `$days` are get the Date value from array.
 My select query is not work with these date value of `PHP` variable please solve its.

```
function checkexpiretime($valid)
    {
        $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
        foreach($valid as $validity)
        {
             echo $createdon=$validity->CreatedOn;
             echo $days=$validity->days;
        }
        echo $query="SELECT * FROM jos_generatekey WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN DATE_ADD('".$createdon."',".INTERVAL $days DAY.")". "AND CURDATE()"; 
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $checkexpire = $db->loadObjectList();
        print_r($checkexpire);
        return $checkexpire;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a php variable to mysql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999458/pass-a-php-variable-to-mysql-query)

Comment: is $valid a multi-dimensional array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query should be like this:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM jos_generatekey WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN DATE_ADD('".$createdon."',INTERVAL ". $days ." DAY) AND CURDATE()";
```

Comment: $query= "SELECT * FROM jos_generatekey WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN DATE_ADD('".$createdon."',INTERVAL ". $days ." DAY)";
your query is running but use it with current date function